# What causes a java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object;?

Tags: jsp, struct

I have a problem with the following code:

```
 List<book> list = new ArrayList();
    if(request.getAttribute("bookDeatils")!=null)
    {
        list = (ArrayList)request.getAttribute("bookDeatils");
            System.out.println("inside loop List --- "+list.size());
            for(book book : list)
                {
                out.println("<tr><td>"+book.getId()+"</td></tr>");
        }
          }
    System.out.printl``n(" List --- "+list.size());
%>
```

It is showing `java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object;`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please take note of my edits when asking questions on Stack Overflow. Additionally, please take some time to read our [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 2):

Your `List<book>` is *actually* a `List<Object[]>`. This will cause a CCE in that enhanced for loop.

That can happen when you're doing something like `SELECT b.id, b.title FROM Book b` instead of `SELECT b FROM Book b` using JPA.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, your code style is very poor. Do not start Java classnames with lowercase. This is confusing to fellow developers and future maintainers. Learn [Java Naming Coventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367). Also do not write Java code in JSP files. Java code belongs in Java classes. You should use taglibs/EL only in JSP files. Learn [Servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) and [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info). Your whole loop can easily be done as follows then:

```html
<c:forEach items="${bookDeatils}" var="bookDetail">
    <tr><td>${bookDetail.id}</td></tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like getAttribute is returning an Array and you are trying to cast that into an array list.  You cannot do that, instead you need to save the getAttribute results in an array

```
book[] list;
list = (book[])request.getAttribute("bookDeatils");
```

Also, its against the standard Java naming conventions to have your class name start with a lower case letter.

Comment: it showing java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to [Lcom.rec.bookbank.persitencejavafile.book; exception

Answer (score 0):

If you posted the stacktrace, we could determine the exact line. However, when using generic collections, mixing generic and non generic collections is the recipe for disaster.

Your first line should look like this:

```
    List<book> list = new ArrayList<book>();
```

If the getAttribute method returns an array, there's no point in using a List only to iterate with the foreach loop. You can do the same with the array, but checking that it is not null first.

And also, naming class book with lowercase is against Java conventions.